# looking for a list of values in a list - Python

Tags: python, list, loops, search

am looping big lists looking for a list of values in that big list. The bellow is a C++ tranditional way in python to find a value or a set of values, but am pretty sure that there should a better way to do it spcially using python. Any suggestions?

a better and faster way to find a list of values in another list

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3]
list_b = [1, 5, 4, 7, 2, 6, 8, 9]
list_resutl = []

for number_a in list_a:
    for number_b in list_b:
        if number_a == number_b:
            list_resutl.append(number_a)

print(list_resutl)
1, 2
```

Comment: `list_result = list(set(list_a).intersection(list_b))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
list_resutl = [item for item in list_a if item in list_b]
```

#### Code:

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3]
list_b = [1, 5, 4, 7, 2, 6, 8, 9]

list_resutl = [item for item in list_a if item in list_b]
print(list_resutl)
```

#### Output:

```
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert each list to a set, then use set intersection.

```py
list_result = list(set(list_a) & set(list_b))
```